# PHP cambiar imágenes

Tags: php

```
<?php

$row= "SELECT" * FROM ventiladores "

switch ($row['estado']({
case  '0':
      $cambio = 'img/ aspas_rojo.gif';
      break;
case  '1':  
      $cambio = 'img/ aspas_verdes.gif';
      break;
default:
      $cambio 0 = 'img/ aspas_amarillo.gif';
```

hola buenas necesito que cuando sea 0 la imagen roja salga y cambia a verde cuando sea 1 de ante mano muchas gracias

Comment: El código compartido contiene numerosos  errores que harán que no funcione. Algunos los puedes ver en la propia pregunta sólo con mirar cómo se está  coloreando el código (te sobran algunas comillas), otros te  darán error cuando se ejecute (faltan comillas o problemas de sintaxis en alguna asignación), finalmente otros también puede que se vean cuando cargue la página (esos espacios en blanco en la url de la imagen pueden crear problemas).... Debes depurar tu código poco a poco, mirar los errores (añade `error_reporting(E_ALL);` al principio de tu página) y actualizar tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que lo hagas asi:

```
$imgs = ['img/aspas_rojo.gif','img/aspas_verdes.gif','img/aspas_amarillo.gif'];
// Obteniendo imagen
$imgs[$row['estado']]; 
/*
 * mostrara la imagen dependiendo de la posicion del estado, si es:
 * 0 = rojo
 * 1 = verde
 * 2 = amarillo
 */
```